# How to display nested JSON object in the next row of mdc-layout-grid in Ember?

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, mdc-components

I want to display a nested JSON object in the next row of the grid. I am using Ember and mdc-layout-grid.

My JSON data is as follows:

```
data = [{
"amzOrderId": "403-8957866-2673902",
"financialEventType": "SHIPMENT",
"timestamp": 1570025882722,
"numOfItems": 1,
"nested": [{
"amzOrderId": "405-3430902-0842748",
"financialEventType": "SHIPMENT",
"timestamp": 1570025882722,
"numOfItems": 1}]},
{
"amzOrderId": "171-9021455-7043516",
"financialEventType": "SHIPMENT",
"timestamp": 15700258888722,
"numOfItems": 1,
"nested":null,
}]
```

My hbs file to render:

```
<li class="sales-list-row">
  {{#mdc-layout-grid as |grid|}}
    {{#grid.inner as |inner|}}
      {{#inner.cell class="bought" span=2}}
        <h3 class="bought__value">{{get data "numOfItems"}}</h3>
      {{/inner.cell}}
      {{#inner.cell class="purchased" span=2}}
        <span class="purchased__text">Purchased</span>
        <h3 class="purchased__value">{{format-date (get data "timestamp") "date"}}</h3>
      {{/inner.cell}}
      {{#inner.cell class="id" span=2}}
        <h4 class="id__value">{{get data "amzOrderId"}}</h4>
      {{/inner.cell}}        
    {{/grid.inner}}
  {{/mdc-layout-grid}}
</li>
```

Now I want to render "nested" object values just in the next row if it is present (move to next data[element] in case nested is null). How do I approach this problem? I have tried a few methods but they are not working.

Comment: You should normalize your data in component's JavaScript class and use the normalized data in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the answer helps anyone. It was easy I added this loop at end of above HBS file:

```
{{#if data.nested}}
    {{#each data.nested as |row|}}
      {{nested-row data1=row}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

and the component nested-row.hbs will have the same code like the above HBS file but we need to use get data1. Hope it helps!!